# How to pass variable value in php array

Tags: php, arrays

From WordPress custom text field values come: Like

```
text_field_words = 'Orange','Mango','banana'
```

With

```
$var_word= get_option('text_field_words');
```

Now I want to use this variable in Array. I tried but value assigned as single value. Please help.

```
$my_array = array($var_word);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You php script receive a string `text_field_words`, so you just need to do is explode it into array.

```
$my_array = explode(",",$var_word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's clear something first.

This line of yours

```
text_field_words = 'Orange','Mango','banana'
```

Should be

```
$text_field_words = 'Orange, Mango, banana';
```

If you're storing this string into wp_option table you can get those values using

```
$text_field_words = get_option( 'your_option_key', '' );
```

Now to your question you can get string into array as follows: (You've $text_field_words and it has your string "Orange", ... )

```
$text_field_words_array = explode(",", $text_field_words);
print_r($text_field_words_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Orange
    [1] =>  Mango
    [2] =>  banana
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`text_field_words` should be a string, i. e. `'Orange,Mango,banana'` OR `"'Orange','Mango','banana'"`

```
$var_word = "'Orange','Mango','banana'";
$my_array = explode(',',str_replace("'", '', $var_word));
```

DEMO:- https://3v4l.org/0FM5p